# How should I handle different input sizes in graph convolution networks?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, geometric-deep-learning

I'm a student beginning to study deep learning, and would like to practice with a simple project using a Graph Convolutional Network.

However, I'm not quite sure how to handle different input sizes of graphs for the GCN. How would I do this?

Is zero-padding the only way to solve this problem? While zero-padding is applicable to CNNs, I'm not sure if it is for a GCN.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you provide some details about the problem you're trying to solve? I might be able to point you to some relevant literature.

Comment: Sorry to late reply. I hope to use GCN to study protein structure and its relevant property. As you know different protein has different length of sequence, hence different size of graph.